Can a U.S. federal appellate court transfer a case to another federal appellate court?
Is there any published decisional authority recognizing that a (U.S.) federal appellate court has discretion to transfer a case to another appellate court? Which would seem to be appropriate response to a plainly erroneous order issued by a district court in the putative transferee circuit that transferred venue to district court in putative transferor circuit.
SPECIFICS: USDC for PAMD transferred case, purportedly pursuant to 28 U.S.C. 1406(a) but in disregard of determinative and uncontroverted record facts (including Pf's IFP status and verified assertion of inability to litigate in transferor forum), to TNED, which dismissed with prejudice while disregarding plain error in venue transfer, thus prompting appeal to Sixth Circuit.
But even a precedential decision issued by the Sixth Circuit -- which is exceedingly unlikely in case with pro se party and nil prospect of oral argument -- would have no precedential effect upon courts in the Third Circuit (including the PAMD), and at least two circuits affirmatively hold that a USCA lacks authority to order intercircuit remand.  Therefore, the best solution would seem to be for the Sixth Circuit to transfer the appeal to the USCA for the Third Circuit, thus avoiding (sub rosa) need to demonstrate manifest hostility of TNED in ordering dismissal.
Could a FRAP 12.1 motion, in combination with Rule 60(b), (d) and/or All Writs motion to PAMD, work?
Resort to MDL panel, based on reasoning that erroneous venue-transfer created a second case?
How about invoking Carmark Amendment to demonstrate ability of Defendants / Appellees to litigate in PAMD?

Please spell out all acronyms at least once.

U.S. federal appellate courts do not have the power to transfer a case to another federal appellate court when it has jurisdiction.

@Peter Revised per your answer.

An appellate court cannot transfer a case based solely on venue, but they can transfer a case, if they lack jurisdiction, to another circuit that has it, under 28 USC 1631:

Whenever ... an appeal ... is noticed for or filed with such a court
and that court finds that there is a want of jurisdiction, the court
shall, if it is in the interest of justice, transfer such ... appeal
to any other such court ... in which the ... appeal could have been
brought at the time it was filed or noticed.

I've personally seen this done at the Federal Circuit (both on the transferor and transferee side), whose jurisdiction is based on subject matter rather than region, and therefore it deals with exotic issues of appellate jurisdiction with some frequency.
Obviously this is going to happen rarely though, and in the specific facts presented by the question, the 6th circuit would plainly have jurisdiction as it was an appeal from a final judgment of a court in Tennessee. The 6th Circuit could opine on the question of the propriety of the transfer, but, you're right, this would not be binding precedent in future cases in the 3rd Circuit.
But s. 1631 wouldn't allow the 6th Circuit to transfer directly to the 3rd simply because it believed the PA court was wrong to transfer venue to the TN court. Venue isn't the same as jurisdiction. It's conceivable (if unlikely) the 6th could've reversed and remanded back to TN and ordered TN to transfer back to PA, however. That would have been an interesting tennis match indeed.
The plaintiff alternatively could have (and probably should have) attempted an interlocutory appeal from the Pennsylvania court prior to transfer, or applied for a writ of mandamus, to the 3rd Circuit.
PS - The question asks for decisional authority. This is the Federal Circuit case I was referencing.
